# running into errors installing Nuxt3

Tags: node.js, installation, nuxt.js

I'm running into an issue with installing Nuxt, I'm new to this, going off of documentation and videos that I can find, but still I'm learning and getting quite desperate, mainly i followed the documentation on installation from [Nuxt website](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/installation). I'm running into errors straight on the first command:

```
npx nuxi@latest init Nuxt3App

√ Which package manager would you like to use?
npm
o Installing dependencies...                                                                                  11:39:23
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'E:\Coding_Projects\Nuxt3App\node_modules\@nuxt'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\@nuxt'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Coding_Projects\Nuxt3App\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.2 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.34407.143) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python312\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\uzivatel\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.11.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\uzivatel\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.11.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\uzivatel\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\20.11.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: E:\Coding_Projects\Nuxt3App\node_modules\@parcel\watcher) while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (E:\Coding_Projects\Nuxt3App\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:271:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\Coding_Projects\Nuxt3App\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\uzivatel\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-11T10_39_24_827Z-debug-0.log

 ERROR  Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
```

I've tried looking for answers, found out that I should try to check if I have installed the newest version of python... I have also i made sure that the path to the python.exe is in enviromental variables, I also checked if i have the VS2019 with Desktop development C++ workload. When I didn't know what else to do I tried to ignore the errors above and just ran the rest of the commands that are in the Nuxt documentation but that just resulted in more erros (suprisingly).

```
npm install
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Coding_Projects\Nuxt3App\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.2 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.34407.143) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python312\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\uzivatel\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.11.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\uzivatel\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.11.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\uzivatel\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\20.11.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\@parcel\\watcher\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: E:\Coding_Projects\Nuxt3App\node_modules\@parcel\watcher) while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (E:\Coding_Projects\Nuxt3App\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:271:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Coding_Projects\\Nuxt3App\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\Coding_Projects\Nuxt3App\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\uzivatel\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-11T10_56_55_786Z-debug-0.log
```

```
npm run dev -- -o

> dev
> nuxt dev -o

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\Coding_Projects\Nuxt3App\node_modules\nuxi\bin\nuxi.mjs'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.11.0
```

Comment: Try to move your `Nuxt3App` to other directory outside of `Coding_Projects`. I encountered this kind of issue previously and I think is was caused by the directory name. Directory name without special characters should be fine.